# query regarding image/audio/video upload in php

Tags: php, image, upload

I want to implement validation on image files (`.jpg`, `.png`, `.gif`) in such a way that if a user changes the extension of html into jpeg then the system will restrict him that this file is in an invalid format. I have implement the validation on file extension, but I want to implement this validation as well.

And I am uploading video (`.wav`, `.flv`, `.mp4`) and audio (`.mp3`) files as well, and if someone upload file with wrong extension, the system will restrict him. How I can do this?

Comment: What kind of restriction are you talking about? Rejecting the file? Blocking (black-listing?) the user?

Comment: Dont you mean reject? so if the extension is not jpg png or gif than throw a validation message...

Comment: You can check the 'type' field ($_FILES['field name']['type']).

Answer (score 0):

tried [finfo_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) - required pecl fileinfo, php 5.3 and above,
this function will return a REAL mime type of an uploaded file,
based on this info, you can do comparison and blocking any unwanted extension (mime)